# local notification at different times everyday

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I would like to know what is the best approach to do if I want to fire notifications for more than one time each day everyday.

I did some research and read that notifications for the next day cannot be fired unless the user opens the app the next day and updated the notification. Is that true? is there anyway I can do it without the need of the user opening the app everyday?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule up to [64](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) local notifications. There is no limit on the time period; you can schedule them years in advance if you like.

That said, if you need some mechanism to schedule new notifications, even if the app is not running at all (e.g. because the user terminated it), you need a background mode for that. [Fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56) is probably the way to go here, as it doesn't need a special trigger. You could also send silent push notifications in order to wake the app, make the calculations and schedule the new notifications.